# Buying foreign exchange in India without a bill: illegal?

Tags: india, foreign-exchange

Is it illegal to buy foreign exchange without a bill in India? Also, is it illegal to convert foreign exchange to INR through an unauthorized dealer? If yes, which laws are broken?

Answer (score 1):

This would be in violation of FEMA (Foreign Exchange Management Act). Then depending on specifics it would be bunch of tax law, money laundering etc.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be specific on what FEMA says in this regard?